# Adding "cache" in Clear-Site-Data slows down page loading

Tags: http-headers, clear-site-data

I have added "Clear-Site-Data" header with the following directives: "cache", "storage". This causes the page loading time to increase significantly. After removing the "cache" directive, the loading time returns back to normal. I have read in the Mozilla documentation about what all things "cache" clears, but my site does not create any cache as verified from the console debugger. So why does "cache" slow down the page loading?

Comment: On google chrome? There's an ongoing issue in chromium with this, see here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762417